# Django CkEditor Load Custom Plugin - Not Working

Tags: django, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, django-ckeditor

I'm creating a custom CkEditor for Django. I followed https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1.html and tried to load the plugin but it doesn't. When I put other plugins into my static folder (`lib/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/MYPLUGIN`) and try to load them, it works.
Maybe someone can help me.

Console error:

```
ckeditor.js:98 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/utils/plugin.js?t=I3I8 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
ckeditor.js:255 Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "utils" was not found at "http://127.0.0.1:8000/lib/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/utils/plugin.js?t=I3I8".
    at CKEDITOR.resourceManager.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:255)
    at e (ckeditor.js:250)
    at Array.z (ckeditor.js:250)
    at y (ckeditor.js:250)
    at ckeditor.js:251
```

Comment: You said it worked when you put plugins in plugins folder. So what's the problem?

Comment: I mean other plugins work when I put them in plugins folder. My plugin doesnt work when I put it in my plugins folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**
I accidentally named `plugin.js` `plugins.js` (with `s`).